# Django, error al importar modulo en virtualenv

Tags: python, django, github, rutas, virtualenv

Estoy intentando levantar el Django de [django_datajsonar](https://github.com/datosgobar/django-datajsonar) con `sudo python3 manaje.py runserver` en un `virtualenv` y me devuelve

> Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
> ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

Cuando lo ejecuto sin `sudo` el error es:

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests.settings'
```

En el ambiente virtual tengo instalado los siguientes paquetes:

```
chardet==3.0.4
ckanapi==4.0
click==7.1.2
croniter==0.3.34
Django==1.11.29
django-environ==0.4.1
django-model-utils==4.0.0
django-rq==2.1.0
django-rq-scheduler==1.1.3
django-solo==1.1.3
docopt==0.6.2
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
idna==2.10
iso8601==0.1.12
isodate==0.6.0
jdcal==1.4.1
jsonschema==2.6.0
natsort==7.0.1
openpyxl==3.0.4
pkg-resources==0.0.0
pydatajson==0.4.67
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2020.1
PyYAML==5.3.1
redis==3.5.3
requests==2.24.0
requests-mock==1.8.0
rfc3987==1.3.7
rq==1.5.0
rq-scheduler==0.10.0
six==1.15.0
unicodecsv==0.14.1
Unidecode==0.4.21
urllib3==1.25.10
XlsxWriter==1.3.0
```

Lei por ahi que tal vez el problema es el path de Django a mi ambiente virtual, pero no se bien como establecerlo. De todos modos no estoy seguro de que ese sea el problema. Tampoco se bien en que carpeta se ubica el `settings.py` que comenta el repo que cite...va en la misma carpeta que el `manage.py`??

gracias anticipadas

Comment: leer el error, dice que no encuentra el modulo tests.settings

Comment: si @teurydiaz el tema es que settings.py esta ubicado en la carpeta del proyecto, en este caso `/home/juan/Python/django-datajsonar/django_datajsonar`
por eso vengo a preguntar...

Comment: @teurydiaz y tambien puse un settings.py en `/home/juan/Python/django-datajsonar/django_datajsonar/tests` pero nada

Comment: La variable de entorno `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=conf.settings.local` es la que indica dónde va el `settings`. O sea, dentro de `conf/settings`. Necesitamos saber qué settings usas para poder ayudarte en el error.